# Create a new column in excel with a condition

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a new column called Book in which I take data from a column called Exposure. If the value from the exposure column is 0, I want it to return 100, else I want to retain the same value. 
This is what I've already tried:

```
df['Book'] = np.where(df['Exposure']==0,100,)
```

how do I get it to return the same value if it's not zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
df['Book'] = df['Exposure'].replace(0, 100)
```

Comment: I need to use np.where unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, like that maybe ?  df['Book'] = np.where(df['Exposure']==0,100, df['Exposure'])